# Streaming large data from different clients at the same time

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, streaming, task-parallel-library

This is a bit architecture and code issue. I have a lot of source url's containing huge files that come from many different clients that I have to download and save on filesystem.

I have hardware limits on RAM. So I want to buffer each stream in chunks of bytes and I think it will be good idea to initiate one thread for each downloading of a stream.

I have added a coding for initiating a thread/task using Task Parallel Library as such:

```
public Task RunTask(Action action)
{
    Task task = Task.Run(action);

    return task;
}
```

and I pass for the action parameter the following method:

```
public void DownloadFileThroughWebStream(WebClient webClient, Uri src, string dest, long buffersize)
{
    Stream stream = webClient.OpenRead(src);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[buffersize];
    int len;
    using (BufferedStream bufferedStream = new BufferedStream(stream))
    {
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(Path.GetFullPath(dest), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            while ((len = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, len);
                fileStream.Flush();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And I for testing purposes try to download some resources from http uri's as by initiating a thread/task for each specific download:

```
[Test]
public async Task DownloadSomeStream()
{
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/video-sample/metaxas-keller-Bell.mpeg");

    List<Uri> streams = new List<Uri> { uri, uri, uri};

    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    var path = "C:\\TMP\\";
    //Create task for each of the streams from uri
    int c = 1;
    foreach (var uri in streams)
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        Task task = taskInitiator.RunTask(() => DownloadFileThroughWebStream(webClient, uri, Path.Combine(path,"File"+c), 8192));
        tasks.Add(task);
        c++;
    }
    Task allTasksHaveCompleted = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    await allTasksHaveCompleted;
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'D:\TMP\File4' because it is being used by another process'
```

on line:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(Path.GetFullPath(dest), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
```

So there are two things that i dont understand with this exception:

1. Why it is not allowed to write? and how another process is allocating the file?
2. Why do it want to save `file4` when I have only added 3 url's, so I only should have files: `file1, file2, and file3` ?

Also, other questions that could be nice to get some thoughts on:

1. Is it right approach what I am doing in regards to what I want to achieve? Am I doing the Task initiations using Task Parallel Library correct?
2. Any tips and trick, best practices, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

> Why it is not allowed to write? and how another process is allocating
>   the file?

The file is not locked by another process, but by the same process.  If you open a file for write, you basically get an exclusive lock for it.  When you try to open the file again for writing from another task, it is locked and that is why you get the error.

To handle this case, you should put a `lock` around writing the data to disk.  **You should have a separate lock object for every unique file name you are writing to, and be careful to use the proper lock!**

> Why do it want to save file4 when I have only added 3 url's, so I only
>   should have files: file1, file2, and file3 ?

This is because you capture the variable `c` in the delegate you pass to `Task.Run`.  Since these tasks normally start after the loop is over, the value of `c` is now 4.  See [here](https://www.simplethread.com/c-closures-explained/) for more information about closures.

Answer (score 0):

We can create download method which can execute downloading:

```
async Task DownloadFile(string url, string location, string fileName)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(url, $"{location}{fileName}");
    }
}
```

And the above method can be called by `Task.Run()` to execute simultaneous download of files:

```
IList<string> urls = new List<string>()
{
    @"http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/video-sample/metaxas-keller-Bell.mpeg",
    @"https://...",
    @"https://..."
};

string location = "D:";
Directory.CreateDirectory(location);

Task.Run(async () =>
{
    var tasks = urls.Select(url => 
    {
        var fileName = url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf('/'));
        return DownloadFile(url, location, fileName);
    }).ToArray();
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```